# Divide a number proportionately to each row based on the value of a column in that row MySQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to distribute an amount proportionately to each row of a table based on the value of a column, 'value' and it's percentage of the sum of that column for all rows.  For example

```
AmounttoDistribute = 200
CurrentTotal = 100
Row 1 value = 25
Row 2 Value = 50
Row 3 Value = 15
Row 4 Value = 10
```

I want to make it where

```
Row 1 will receive 50
Row 2 will receive 100
Row 3 will receive 30 
Row 4 will receive 20
```

I've tried a couple different while loops but so far the results are very different than what I'm trying to achieve.  I've already got the $AmounttoDistribute and $SumofValue in variables which I know to be correct.  Here's what I've tried:

```
$val = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT Value FROM Table WHERE columnX = 1 AND columnY = 1");
$Result = mysqli_fetch_array($val);
$value = $Result['Value'];

while($Result = mysqli_fetch_array($val)){ 
mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE Table SET Value = Value + (Value / $SumofValue * $AmounttoDistribute) WHERE columnX = 1 AND columnY = 1");
```

I've also tried the while loop below where I already have a variable for AmounttoDistribute divided by SumofValue, ($AmountPerEach1):

```
$val = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT Value FROM Table WHERE columnX = 1 AND columnY = 1");
$Result = mysqli_fetch_array($val);
$value = $Result['Value'];

while($Result = mysqli_fetch_array($val)){ 
mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE Table SET Value = Value + (Value * $AmountPerEach1) WHERE columnX = 1 AND columnY = 1");
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: You need to change that value in the database or you want to just show the value divided?

Comment: I need to add the new amount to the pre-existing value so that the totals in the database after adding the AmounttoDistribute to the rows are now: row 1 = 75, row 2 = 150, row 3 = 45, row 4 = 30

Comment: Ok, and when the values doesn't added up in an equal division, which one will receive the difference? Or it can be randomly chosen?

Comment: I'm using 7 decimal places after the zero, so any remainder beyond that will be inconsequential

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the *AmountToDistribute* and *CurrentTotal*, you can do this via one simple SQL statement.

Basically:

```
UPDATE table SET column = column + ((AmountToDistribute/CurrentTotal)*column);
```

Specifically for this case:

```
UPDATE Table SET Value = Value + 2*Value;
```

Comment: Well I feel dumb...Thanks a lot :)